# Cloud Build run python script using custom container fails

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-build

I'm using a customer container `apache/airflow` from docker-hub to run a simple python script `test_file.py` and it executes without problem.

```
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
print('import works. DONE')
```

```
docker run -it --rm --name test-container -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/tests -w /usr/src/tests apache/airflow python test_file.py
```

Trying to replicate the the same execution with Cloud Build with following build configuration, `test-build-config.yml`:

```
steps:
- name: 'apache/airflow'
  entrypoint: 'python'
  args: ['test_file.py']
```

```
gcloud builds submit --config=test-build-config.yml
```

Fails, where the execution had issue with locating the module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_file.py", line 1, in <module>
    from airflow.models import BaseOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'
```

With some debugging I located the module at
`/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py`

so I added it to `PYTHONPATH` variable in the cloud build config

```
env: ["PYTHONPATH=/home/airflow/.local/lib"]
```

But it had no effect on the execution issue. Would really appreciate to get some idea on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Modifying PYTHONPATH is wrong. It appears that you are trying to include packages alongside your code. Instead, create a **requirements.txt** and specify which dependencies should be set up during the build.

Comment: Changed the PYTHONPATH to `["PYTHONPATH=/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages"]`  has fix the build. This is related to this [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14520#issuecomment-787437187)